# Combining two Json feeds in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, feed

Good day stack people,

I'm doing research for my self on how to combine two Json feeds in one and display them in one timeline by date using JS or jQuery.

For example we will have two json files file1.json and file2.json (one from twitter and another from filckr).

I need "n" numbers of latest items and show append them to show by items time.

Any ideas or hints?

Thank you!

P.S. Example feeds: http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/ignaty.json?count=5 and http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?%20id=675729@N22&lang=en-us&format=json

Lets pick only any one value from each.

Comment: It would help if you could show the format of the two files.

Comment: For example http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/ignaty.json?count=5 and http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?%20id=675729@N22&lang=en-us&format=json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some method that should do that (you need to tweak it though).

Essentially you request the two APIs and then (once both requests are completed) you sort an array of normalized objects.

```
var all = [];
var waiting = 2; // number of services you request

// once you get response1 or response2
function parseFlickr(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
     // normalize item here depending on service format (parse date)
     var normalized = {};
     normalized.date = new Date(Date.parse(item.date));
     all.push(normalized);
  });

  if(--waiting == 0) { onDone(); }
}

function onDone() {
  all.sort(function(a,b) {
    // switch -1 and +1 to invert ordering
    return (a.date < b.date ? -1 : (a.date > b.date ? +1 : 0));
  });

  // do the rendering/appending (you might limit the amount here)
}
```